# Using Java DateTimeFormatter for date range

Tags: java, parsing, date

I have expressions such as:

**Tuesday, May 5, 11:15-12:45 p.m.**

I can express them in `DateTimeFormatter` as:

**DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("EEEE, MMM dd, hh:mm-hh:mm a")**

But how do I get `DateTimeFormatter` to return a range of date/times instead of just one date?

Comment: Range of dates between what?

Comment: I think **DateTimeFormatter** will not return range of date/times or as you want. You need to figure it yourself how you want.

Comment: @MadProgrammer - range of dates between May 5 11:15 p.m. and May 5 12:45 p.m. in this case.

Comment: Oh, I see, and in what increments?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by increments - the fields present in the LocalDateTime or ZonedDateTime (or any TemporalAccessor) depend on the fields provided in the format pattern.